# Uploading html file in github

Tags: html, r, github, r-markdown

I have created a html file using R markdown, and when I open it in browser, it looks exactly how I want. But if I upload the same html file in github and open there, it gives me totally different outlook.

https://github.com/syedaash/ML-Project/blob/main/ML_project.html is the link of my html doc in github, which is not I want. But if I open the html file from my local computer in a browser it's good. Why is that and what to do?

Answer (score 2):

GitHub does not automatically load and render an HTML file because GitHub is about code, therefore going straight to any file will display the internals of that file, not how it would be rendered on a browser.

The [HTML Preview project](https://github.com/htmlpreview/htmlpreview.github.com) has a way to render HTML files hosted on GitHub, you can just append your HTML path like [so](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/syedaash/ML-Project/blob/main/ML_project.html) and put it on your README for example:

```
https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/syedaash/ML-Project/blob/main/ML_project.html
```

However, I would recommend that you look into creating a [GitHub Page](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site) for your project, you only need to make a few changes and turn it on and you got it.

**Edit:** So I checked on your status @Alex and it looks like you created the GitHub Page for your GitHub profile, which is not rendering your profile properly. Maybe this tutorial from [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/f1-u3-github-pages) will be easier to understand that you can get GitHub Pages rendered for EVERY repo if you wish. You can see I do that with my own [simple project](https://github.com/VietThan/QuocHoiXV) with its [live site](https://vietthan.github.io/QuocHoiXV/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output of the file (what it looks like when opened in a browser, you have to enable Github pages for your repository, [more here](https://pages.github.com/). The link you sent is just the HTML text file that you have written, not what it actually would look like in a browser. Github pages hosts the HTML text file (link you sent) so that you can actually see it in a browser window.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub](https://github.com) is to share code not to deploy website. So now you should use [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) this is my sample website [Hariienesh1901](https://hariienesh1901.github.io/) hosted by GitHub Pages. See tutorial from GitHub https://guides.github.com/features/pages/